# How to create a column on an existing datatable with a default value for update only

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.1

I am doing a major refactoring of an existing ASP-Core project. This application is connected to a MS-SQL database using Entity Framework Core, Code First approach.

I would like to add a non-nullable property to a `DbSet` which would be defaulted to a certain value when performing the update (to reflect this change on previously inserted entities), but not after the update is performed.

I managed to update the existing entities by adding a DefaultValue in the `migrationBuilder.AddColumn` method.

**Problem is : this default value persists**, ie. if I try to add later on a Foo without a LastName, LastName would be defaulted into the DB, which is not what I want (I would like the DB to reject the insertion instead).

How can I set a *temporary default value* using Code First Approach?

The only way I've found so far is to modify the Default Value for this column from MS SQL Server Management Studio after applying this migration, which is not ideal.

```
//Existing version
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(240), Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

}

//Updated version
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(240), Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(240), Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; } //Should not be null
}

public partial class FooUpdateMigration : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder) {
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "LastName",
            table: "Foos",
            maxLength: 240,
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: "Unknown for old Foos");

    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder) {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "LastName",
            table: "Foos");
    }
}

public class FooManager
{

    public void AddFoo(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        Foo newFoo = new Foo(){
            FirstName="John",
            LastName = null
        };

        context.Foos.Add(newFoo);
        context.SaveChanges(); //DO NOT THROW EXCEPTION, LastName is defaulted to "Unknown for old Foos" into the datable
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error "SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'LastName', table 'Foos'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails." How you're getting the default value when you have set **nullable: false** in migration's Up function?

Comment: @AribYousuf I am not sure that I understand your question. I set nullable = false AND defaultValue = "default string" in the migration Up function. This default value is being assigned to the column into the database (I can see it from MS SQL Server Manager)

Comment: My bad I forgot to add **HasDefaultValue**  in **OnModelCreating** function that's why it's not working for me but I've fixed it and you can follow my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Override **SaveChanges** in DbContext class and follow below code:

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry<Foo> entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<Foo>().Where(entry => entry.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("LastName") == null))
        {
            switch (entry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    entry.Entity.LastName = "Your value";
                    break;

                case EntityState.Modified:
                    entry.Entity.LastName = "Your value";
                    break;
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Why do you set a value for LastName? This is exactly what I don't want, as explained in my question. Quote: "I would like the DB to reject the insertion instead."

Comment: Ok then instead of insertion what should be the behavior? Will it throw exception?